# Jquery UI date-picker focusout

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, focusout

Jquery UI date picker loses focus when selecting a date. Are there any alternatives to this? 
If not, how do I achieve the standard web bevaviour of user entering data into the input field and not losing focus while doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using onselect function of the date picker